# Regex expression with an "=" character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript that needs to catch an alphanumeric string followed by whitespace (or not), an equal sign (=) followed by whitespace (or not), then end with an alphanumeric.  Here are some correct strings:

```
Computer45 = Upstairs22
Computer45=Upstairs22
45Computer=22Upstairs
45Computer  =22Upstairs
45Computer=  22Upstairs
```

I am using the following expression but it is failing each time in javacript.

```
var regx = /^\w+\s*=\s*\w+/
var pair = document.getElementById("userInput").value;//by id
isValid = regx.test(pair);
```

It seems straight forward.  However it fails.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: The regex looks valid, but I hope you're  defining it as a literal (eg in `/`), not just directly in your code file as you've shown? Also, what do you mean by "fails"? Doesn't match? Javascript error? Is there any information in the console?

Comment: What I mean by fail is that it does not match.  Sorry posted the old var.  It is actually: var regx = /^\w\s*=\s*\w/  So yes, it is enclosed just like @Oriol indicated.  I also added the + so now it reads: var regx = /^\w+\s*=\s*\w+/  However it still does not match when I debug it using firebug:  The regx.test(pair) returns false for the above examples.

Comment: I've just opened up the JS console while on this page... `var regx = /^\w+\s*=\s*\w+/;
regx.test("45Computer=  22Upstairs");` It returned `true`. Are you sure there isn't some other code interfering?  Fiddle proving it works: https://jsfiddle.net/p1wzp910/ (excuse the fact that I used alerts... It's late). Chrome Version 43.0.2357.65 m. Also works in Firefox 37.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you put the regex in `/`, youre just missing  `+` on your \w

so:

```
^\w+\s*=\s*\w+$
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, [regex literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5) need to be enclosed in `/`:

```js
var regx = /^\w\s*=\s*\w$/
```

Otherwise, the `^` will be treated as a [binary bitwise operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10), which needs an expression before itself, so it will throw.

Anyways, this regex won't match your strings, as @Rooster [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30426881/1529630).